# How can I sort tuples?

Tags: python

Im trying to write a program that has 2 variables (Integer) and that based on those variables print´s them joined and by order (Smaller number to Higher):

Like this:

together((0,39,100,210),(4,20))

printing the following:

(0,4,20,39,100,210)

The code:

```
def together(s,t):
    y = s + t
    z = 0
    if sorted(y) == y:
        print (y)
    else:
        for i in range(len(y)-1):
            if y[z] > y[z+1]:
                y[z+1] = y[z]
        return (y)
   print y
```

If variables are set like the following:

s=1,23,40 and t=9,90

I´m getting this:

```
(1, 23, 40, 9, 90)
```

which is out of order as you can see it should appear the following:

```
(1,9,23,40,90)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just append both tuples and then sort them:

```
def together(s,t):
    return tuple(sorted(s + t))
```

Comment: Is there any other way you could do this by using comparatives to see if the numbers from the 'y' variable are already sorted and if not do it to the whole scheme?

Answer (score 0):

```
T = ((0,39,100,210),(4,20))    
print tuple( sorted( reduce(tuple.__add__, T) ) )
```

This can combine and sort `N number of tuples` within a tuple, so it's not limited to two tuples