# Merging and sorting tuples in Python

Tags: python

The program should be like this:

```
together((0,39,100,210),(4,20))
```

printing the following:

```
(0,4,20,39,100,210)
```

The code:

```
def together(s,t):
    y = s + t
    z = 0
    if sorted(y) == y:
        print (y)
    else:
        for i in range(len(y)-1):
            if y[z] > y[z+1]:
                y[z+1] = y[z]
        return (y)
   print y
```

If variables are set like the following:

```
s=1,23,40
```

and

```
t=9,90
```

I´m getting this:

```
(1, 23, 40, 9, 90)
```

which is out of order as you can see it should appear the following:

```
(1,9,23,40,90)
```

Is there any other way you could do this by using comparatives to see if the numbers from the 'y' variable are already sorted and if not do it to the whole scheme?
Using a type of code like this one where you use to see what´s the bigger number:

```
def bigger(t): 
     bigger = 0 
     for i in range(len(t)-1): 
        if t[i] > bigger: 
        bigger = t[i] 
return bigger
```

Is this possible for getting the same result that you get by doing the solution above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort tuples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320756/how-can-i-sort-tuples)

Comment: `from itertools import chain; tuple(sorted(chain(*((0,39,100,210),(4,20)))))` may be

Comment: I really needed to know other way to do it, that´s why it looks like a duplicate, but not the same idea behind it - tlastowka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
T = ((0,39,100,210),(4,20))    
print tuple( sorted( reduce(tuple.__add__, T) ) )
```

T is your `together` tuple....This uses `reduce`, and in-built `__add__` function of tuples to do the job...